# Assigning Groups based on NA amount

Tags: r, dataframe, na, dplyr

Quite a newbie here - so tell me if I need to provide more.
Im trying to wrap my head around this code for quite a while now, but I never get the desired results. Im trying to assign groups base on "NA" amount in different columns. I created a minimal working dataset to visualise what the problem is - and provided the code I tried to run so far. Eventually I want to create groups based on whether they have 1 missing, 2 missing or three missing Follow Up points.

My Dataset looks as follows:

```
my_data <- data.frame( 
  Follow_Up1 = c(100, 200, 300, 1, NA, NA, 50, 10, 5, NA),
  Follow_Up2 = c(NA,  500 ,400,380,NA, NA, 500, 780,NA,500),
  Follow_up3 = c(NA, NA, 1000, 800,NA, 1200, 1100, 1200, 990, NA) 
) 

follow_Up <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(Group = case_when(is.na(Follow_Up1) & is.na(Follow_Up2) & is.na(Follow_Up3)~1, 
                           !is.na(Follow_Up1) & is.na(Follow_Up2) & is.na(Follow_Up3)~2, 
                           is.na(Follow_Up1) & !is.na(Follow_Up2) & is.na(Follow_Up3)~3,
                           !is.na(Follow_Up1) & !is.na(Follow_Up2) & !is.na(Follow_Up3)~4,
                           !is.na(Follow_Up1) & !is.na(Follow_Up2) & is.na(Follow_Up3)~5,
                           is.na(Follow_Up1) & is.na(Follow_Up2) & !is.na(Follow_Up3)~6, 
                           !is.na(Follow_Up1) & is.na(Follow_Up2) & !is.na(Follow_Up3)~7 
))

Expected Output: 

   Follow_up1  Follow_up2  Follow_Up3 Group 
1   100          <NA>       <NA>       2
2   200          500        <NA>       5
3   300          400        1000       4
4   1            380        800        4 
5   <NA>         <NA>       <NA>       1
6   <NA>         <NA>       1200       6
7   50           500        1100       4
8   10           78         1200       4
9   5            <NA>       990        7
10  <NA>         500        <NA>       2
```

If this doesn't work, I could also just assign Groups base on number of NA´s not order - if this is simpler to code. Tho I have also failed to do so as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it for your second scenario (unordered number of `NA` values), but I'm afraid if the order is important you have to use your own solution, maybe you can make it a little less verbose for when all or non are `NA`s:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(group = sum(is.na(c_across(everything()))), 
         group = ifelse(group == 1, 3, ifelse(group == 3, 1, group))) 


# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Rowwise: 
   Follow_Up1 Follow_Up2 Follow_up3 group
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1        100         NA         NA     2
 2        200        500         NA     3
 3        300        400       1000     0
 4          1        380        800     0
 5         NA         NA         NA     1
 6         NA         NA       1200     2
 7         50        500       1100     0
 8         10        780       1200     0
 9          5         NA        990     3
10         NA        500         NA     2
```

Comment: Thank you, this code worked for me quite well. I tweaked it a little because my dataset includes more variables. I used "sum(is.na(across(starts_with("FU"))))"

Comment: Oh glad it helped. My pleasure. Actually it's `c_across` as you are conducting a rowwise operation. It is used with `rowwise` function mostly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option -

```
vec <- apply(is.na(my_data), 1, paste0, collapse = ' ')
my_data$Group <- match(vec, unique(vec))
my_data

#   Follow_Up1 Follow_Up2 Follow_up3 Group
#1         100         NA         NA     1
#2         200        500         NA     2
#3         300        400       1000     3
#4           1        380        800     3
#5          NA         NA         NA     4
#6          NA         NA       1200     5
#7          50        500       1100     3
#8          10        780       1200     3
#9           5         NA        990     6
#10         NA        500         NA     7
```

Or using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
  is.na() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(across()) %>%
  mutate(Group = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: thank you, I also changed the across to (across(starts_with("FU"))) - but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for

```
my_data$group <- rowSums(is.na(my_data))
```